# Failed to connect to APNS

Tags: ios, apple-push-notifications, apns-php

We are facing a strange problem with APNS.

We have a live app and it is able to send Push Message from the API domain. But we are preparing to move it to another server where we are testing with the IP instead of domain.

We are using the same settings and code, but APNS keeps failing returning the following error:
**NOTICE: Failed to connect to APNS: 0 .**

We have checked thoroughly, we have 2195 and 2196 ports open and SSL installed on our new server.

Can anyone please tell me if APNS keeps failing because of using IP instead of domain name?

Regards,
SG

Comment: Are you testing with wich IP? the one associated with gateway.push.apple.com?? Do you have the APNS certificate in your new server?
did you test if you can access to the APNS server with a `telnet gateway.sandbox.push.apple.com 2195`?

Answer (score 2):

Apple docs say:

> The IP address range for the push service is subject to change; the
>   expectation is that providers will connect by hostname rather than IP
>   address. The push service uses a load balancing scheme that yields a
>   different IP address for the same hostname. However, the entire
>   17.0.0.0/8 address block is assigned to Apple, so you can specify that range in your firewall rules.

Comment: By 'Domain' and 'IP', I meant my own website. For staging we are using the IP instead of domain name, as we cannot change the domain to new server right now. We call normal link with hostname for Push.

Comment: Do you have command line access to your server?, then try first to `telnet gateway.sandbox.push.apple.com 2195` if you cannot connect, check your firewall.
After that try with `openssl s_client -connect gateway.sandbox.push.apple.com:2195 -cert YOURCERT.pem -key YOURKEY.pem` If the connection is successful, you should be able to type a few characters and press enter to disconnect. If there was a problem establishing the connection, openssl will give you an error message. If this works, you have connection from your server to APNS server.